# Will a normality test always agree with a qq plot?

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, intuition, qq-plot

I am trying to evaluate normality assessment of a variable using qq plot and/or a formal test. Let's consider the Jarque-Bera normality test.

Granted that glancing at qq plots is not intended to be a formal test of normality (correct me if I'm wrong), but it can still make judgements about normality very clear and accurate. Then we have a formal normality test, though it lacks the fancy graphs, it's just as conclusive, if not more so.

**Question:**
Will a qq plot always agree with, say, a Jarque-Bera (use other normality test if you so desire in your answer) normality test? I wonder if, under very specific circumstances one might get conflicting signals from these two tools. Or perhaps, if you get conflicting signals, is that **always** a sign that there is a bug or user error or something wrong with the calculations?

Comment: No; it's not always a sign of error. Rejection of any formal test can mean that the sample is large enough to detect non-normality which nevertheless no one need worry about. Formally, the test may be correct in terms of what it is designed to do, but if its real role is to find a practical problem whenever one exists, then the test is often contradicted by (an experienced researcher's interpretation of) a quantile plot. .

Comment: FWIW, the Jarque-Bera test as I've seen it implemented uses asymptotic standard errors for small samples, which is quite wrong in terms of how sample skewness and kurtosis behave even if the distribution really is normal. I am amazed that this simple point isn't made more often. But again it's widespread folklore that formal tests of normality are mostly a waste of time. Usually normality assumptions are at most about errors, **not** the marginal distributions of variables.

Comment: Jarque Bera in particular can easily fail to reject clearly non-normal samples.

Comment: Consider two _different_ tests of normality A and B at the 5% level. For normal datasets, each falsely rejects 5% of of the datasets, but because A and B are different tests, generally they won't reject exactly the _same datasets._ That is they will sometimes disagree. A Q-Q plot as interpreted by any one statistician is just another normality test. So my interpretation of a Q-Q plot will not always agree with the Smith-Jones normality test--nor for that matter even with my office mate's interpretation of the same Q-Q plot. // Different tests use different criteria so results will differ.

Comment: @Nick Cox: formal tests of normality does at least have some didactic value for students, to get some experience with reading qq-plots!